# Matlab error for ODE23t function

Tags: matlab, ode

I am posting the program:

```
 function dz=film(t,H)    
global A eo d e1 ho gr_pn phiup dX Bl Bu    

eo=8.85e-12;
e1=2.5;
phiup=20;
gamma=0.048;
nu=1;
A=1.51e-20;
d=100e-9;
lo=1e-9;
ho=20e-9;
lambda=(2*pi*((e1*d)-((e1-1)*ho))^1.5)/(((eo*e1*((e1-1)^2))^0.5)*phiup);
k=(2*pi)/lambda;
grid_l=4*lambda;
grid_l_dmn=grid_l*((0.5*eo*e1*(e1-1)*(phiup^2))^0.5)/((gamma*(ho^3))^0.5);
grid_point=200;
dX=grid_l_dmn/grid_point;
grd_pn=grid_point+1;


size(dX)
grid_point=200;    
dX=grid_l_dmn/grid_point;    
grd_pn=grid_point+1;    



size(dX)    

for i= 1 : grd_pn    
    z(i) = 4 ;    
    h_initial(i)=ho*    sin(k*    z(i));    
    H_initial(i)=h_initial(i)/ho;    
end    
t=2;    
tm_dmn1=t*(0.5*eo*e1*(e1-1)*(phiup^2))/(3*nu*gamma*ho);    
grid_time=200;    
tm_div=tm_dmn1/grid_time;    
tinitial=0;
gr_tme=grid_time+1;    
for j=1:gr_tme    
    tend=tinitial+tm_div;    
end    
 tspan=[tinitial tend];    
 [t,H]=ode45 ('filmode',tspan,H_initial);    


Bl=(((A/(6*pi*(lo^3)))-((0.5*eo*e1(e1-1)*phiup^2)/((e1*d-(e1-1)*lo)^2)))*(lo^9))/8;    
Bu=(((A/(6*pi*((d-lo)^3)))-((0.5*eo*e1(e1-1)*phiup^2)/((e1*d-(e1-1)*(d-lo))^2)))*((d-lo)^9))/8;    

end    


function dHdt=filmode(t,H)       %declaring the ode

global A eo d e1 gr_pn ho phiup dX Bl Bu



for i=3:gr_pn-3  

    Phi(i)=A/(6*pi*(H(i)^3)*(ho^3))-(8*Bl/((H(i)^9)*(ho^9)))+(8*Bu/((d-(H(i)*ho))^9))-((0.5*eo*e1*(e1-1)*(phiup^2))/(((e1*d)-(e1-1)*H(i)*ho)^2));

    dHdz(i)=(H(i+1)-H(i-1))/(2*dX); 

    d3Hdz3(i)=(H(i+2)-(2*H(i+1))+(2*H(i-1))-H(i-2))/(2*(dX^3));

    d4Hdz4(i)=(H(i+2)-(4*H(i+1))+(6*H(i))-(4*H(i-1))+H(i-2))/(dX^4);    

    dPhidz(i)=(Phi(i+1)-Phi(i-1))/(2*dX); 

    d2Phidz2(i)=(Phi(i+1)-(2*Phi(i))+Phi(i-1))/(dX^2); 

    dHdt=@(t,H)(3*(H(i)^2)*dHdz(i)*d3Hdz3(i))+((H(i)^3)*d4Hdz4(i))-(3*(H(i)^2)*dHdz(i)*dPhidz(i))-  ((H(i)^3)*d2Phidz2(i));   

end    

end `
```

When I attempt to run it I get an error

??? Error using ==> feval
Undefined function or method 'filmode' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in ==> odearguments at 110
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ==> ode45 at 173
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Error in ==> film at 39
 [t,H]=ode45('filmode',tspan,H_initial);

There are threads here which notify this type of error but I am unable to find the link as why this error is occurring for this program
I would be very grateful if someone would look into this as this is very important program for me

Comment: Are you sure you have a function called `filmode` in the workspace?

Comment: Is the function `filmode` saved in a separate MATLAB file called `filmode.m`? Is that file in a directory that i on your MATLAB path or in your current directory? How do you call the function `film`? Is that saved in a separate MATLAB file `film.m`?

Comment: both film and filmode are both contained in the same m file.if you look carefully you will find 2 functions,first one is film and second one is filmode

Comment: Have them in _separate_ m-files. `filmode` must be in `filmode.m`, and `film` in `film.m`.

Comment: Your code does not run at all, `grid_l_dmn` is not defined, `k` is not defined. Contrary to what Robert said, it is entirely possible to define sub-functions in a single `m`-file. To fix your problem, try removing the apostrophes from around `filmode` when you call `ode45`, and add a leading `@` sign (`ode45(@filmode,...`).

Comment: @David I have used `@` sign and still it gives the same error.I have also used `ode23t`and `ode23` but to no use.I have the variables defined but I haven't shown them here.I have edited the program and have shown all the defined variables for your convinience

Comment: Well I just copied your code, changed `'filmode'` to `@filmode` when calling `ode45`, and it did work. There are other errors on your code, but`@filmode` is definitely correct.

Comment: @David Well,can you tell me which version of matlab were you using,i use matlab 2008 and it isn't working

Comment: I'm using 2012 or 2013. 2008 is quite old though, splitting it into two m-files might work in that case. Read the ODE solver documentation (for your version of Matlab) for information about defining your equation.